# AVPlayer not playing large file

Tags: ios, avplayer

I use AVPlayer to play mp4 file and it is ok but there is a problem when i open a large mp4 file(1.3G).

The debug information is as following:
"move failed:Item cannot be played"

Any advice would be appreciated

IOS Vesion:>6.0

Comment: Try compressing the video file and then play it

Comment: Could it be you are out of disk space?

Comment: quick time can play it, but Avplayer can't.  Mp4 file something is wrong. Thank you!